# MySQL string prefix matching when using collation with contractions

Tags: mysql, collation, string-comparison

I have a custom MySQL collation that makes use of a collation with contractions (i.e., a sequence of multiple characters defined as having a single weight). As a simplified example, I have something like this rule defined:

```
<collation name="utf8_my_custom_collation_ci" id="1200">
  <rules>
    <reset>c</reset>
    <p>ch</p>
    <reset>ch</reset>
    <p>d</p>
  </rules>
</collation>
```

This should collate "ch" as though it were a completely separate letter after "C" and before "D", so that cz < ch < d. And it does, so that works nicely.

Now, my question is: how do I perform substring comparisons in a generic manner while treating "C" and "CH" as separate characters? For instance, I want the sets returned by

```
SELECT word WHERE word LIKE 'c%';
SELECT word WHERE word LIKE 'ch%';
```

to be completely disjoint.

I realize this could be done by adding "NOT LIKE" statements, but not without embedding essentially my entire collation logic into each query. If I have 10 or more such contractions defined in the collation, I'd rather not have to manually include all of them in a series of conditions and NOT LIKEs.

If it matters, I'm using MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that 'cz' < 'ch', I generally assume that a contraction with the initial [x] is outside the range of 'xa' and 'xz'. So for searching for [x] plus truncation, you could add a general exclusion:

```
SELECT word WHERE word LIKE '[x]%' AND word > '[x]a%' AND word < '[x]z%'
```

From your description of the contractions, this should work for all of them.